# dynamic multiple insert

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005, insert

I have a form that allows users to insert "items" in a database. A field asks how many items they want to insert. Identical data (apart from their ID) is inserted in the database the number of times they chose. I've found different ways to insert multiple items but not when this is dynamically done. I'm using .net 3.5 and SQLServer 2005. Do I have to use a For...Next statement or is there any other way? Thanks

**UPDATE:** My simplified insert code is as follows:

```
    Dim sqlCmd1 As String

    sqlCmd1 = "INSERT INTO Table_Items (ItemType, ItemDescription, ContactName, ContactEmail) VALUES (@ItemType, @ItemDescription, @ContactName, @ContactEmail);"

    'Dim ID As Integer
    Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ToString()
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim Cmd1 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlCmd1, conn)

    With Cmd1.Parameters
        .Add(New SqlParameter("@ItemType", Textbox1.Text))
        .Add(New SqlParameter("@ItemDescription", Textbox2.Text))
        .Add(New SqlParameter("@ContactName", Textbox3.Text))
        .Add(New SqlParameter("@ContactEmail", Textbox4.Text))

    End With

    Try
        conn.Open()
        ID = Cmd1.ExecuteScalar()
        Server.Transfer("confirmation.aspx")
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        lblError.Text = ex.Message()
    End Try
```

Comment: What do you mean when talking about "dynamically done"? There are many ways to work with DB which one you use? LINQToSql, DataAdapters, StoredProcedures call or whatever? How many items you have to insert at once (eg 10, or 10000) so you maybe have to use bulk processing?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It is a database for a repository of furniture, so it can be from 1 till 50, I suppose. I use SQLServer 2005. Thanks.

Comment: How do you insert 1 item into DB, can you show your code? Or maybe you asking how to do inserts?

Comment: Update with insert code posted, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to go with your style just add call to Cmd1.ExecuteScalar() in cycle

`For i As Integer = 1 To Counter Cmd1.ExecuteScalar()  Next`

But be aware this is certainly **not** right way for general usage. While you keep it small, there are no so much overhead, else better go @anivas way.

Also check [ASP.NET Data Access Tutorials](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials) and I would recommend to switch to **LINQToSql** if it's possible. It will save you a lot of time. Check [Using LINQ to SQL Series](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx), [LINQ via C#](http://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/archive/2009/09/07/linq-via-csharp.aspx) and [Using LINQ to SQL in Visual Basic](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQtoSQL_VB.aspx)

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I will try lear Linq. It is just recently I'm using .net 3.5. Only two or three admin people will be able to do this multiple insert so it will be sparingly used. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is identical data and considering worst case that the number user chooses to insert (how many items) will be reasonably more, to avoid unwanted payload to the database, I would write a stored procedure and just pass the total and the item data. Use XML for item data if the properties are more.

Comment: I cant use xml as It is a SQLServer 2005 database. Thanks.

Comment: You can use it but probably won't: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: XML is a valid datatype in SQL Server 2005